# How to uncheck checkbox when click outside?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a droplist by making a checkbox. If checkbox is checked the droplist appears and disappears..
I want to make a javascript code to uncheck the checkbox when user click outside in a blank area.

I have tried this javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("drop1").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("drop1").checked = false;
</script>
```

But it isn't working.

Here is the input form:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="" id="drop1" />
```

Comment: You have to create click event listeners on both the element and a sufficiently big enough parent element; I should warn you that this is not intuitive design.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below js code to hide when the user clicks outside the dropdown.

include jquery and add this code

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("selector to dropdown list");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if clicked outside
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0)nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
        $( "#drop1" ).prop( "checked", false ); //to uncheck
    }
});
```

Comment: If the jQuery tag is not present, answers are expected to be in pure JavaScript. See the JavaScript tag wiki.

Comment: frankly i'm not pretty good with javascript and Jquery ... so can u provide me a code to implement and let me understand it's logic by my own ... sorry for that

Comment: it would be strange to include a library for a small 5 lines code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a label. Labels act as a large clickable area for their associated control.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the element on the click event and then can write the logic accordingly.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY,
    elementOnClick = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var z = elementOnClick.id;
    if(z!="drop1" && !z.is(":visible"))
    {
       document.getElementById("drop1").checked = false;
    }
});
```

If you purely want to do it in javascript then you can addEventListener on document http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm